# Why does C or C++ “-0” not produce a floating-point −0?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I am trying to collect some edge cases for floating-point arithmetic. The thing is, my attempt with `printf` is not showing me what I want:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex>

int main() {
    double x = -0;
    auto y = sqrt(x);

    printf("x %f y %f \n", x, y);

    return 1;
}
```

Per IEEE, `squareRoot(-0)` is `-0`, but this will print out both x and y to be 0.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve what I want? Would it be through compiler flags or something different?

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  That usage of `auto` looks more like C++.  In C it'll get you an `int`, not the `double` that you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`0` is an integer constant, so `-0` is also an integer which is still `0`.

To get a negative zero, using a floating point constant.

```
double x = -0.0;
```